# Relationship in Database

Tags: database, relational-database

Is there any problem in making a relationship that joins 3 tables with 3 relations?

In my case I have Sales, Sale Details and Products.
I related products and details of sale because I can enter multiple products in details. On the other hand, I related Products Selling because I need some products that belong to a sale.
Is wrong I do this kind of relationship?

I reedited my tables :

Sales: sales_id, date

Sales_Details: sales_id, prodSale_id

Products: product_id, product_info, cost

Products_for_Sale: prodSale_id, product_id, price

[image]

[image]

Consider the following situation :

1. I have a table where Products_for_Sale products belonging sale appears only once. This table is needed because I need to change the selling prices of the products manually, as needed, without changing the overall product table. ( Note that I manually changed the products 1,2,3 and 4 Products_for_Sale).
2. Note that products are repeated for sale because it is a necessity of the business rule (Products are repeated I have more fields that require repetition of the products).
3. For this reason I needed a helper where I put these products only once (Products_for_Sale) table.
4. But I thought about putting a sales_id in Products_for_Sale column to know which belongs to each product sale.

Does my modeling right now ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have 3 tables in the following manner.

**1) Sales (sales_id, date,..)**

**2)Products(product_id, product_info,...)**

**3)sales_products(sales_id,product_id)**

This is [normalized](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) and the best approach for many-many relationships. look [here](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) for more info